# PHP: Image retrieval from MySQL Blob directly into <img> tag

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I've stored my Images into (Medium) BLOB fields and want to retrieve them embedded within my PHP-generated web pages.

When I test retrieving the stored images using

```
header('Content-type: ' . $image['mime_type']);
echo $image['file_data'];
```

everything looks just fine.

However, I have not yet found a way to retrieve the image(s) cleanly into the middle of my documents. For example, using

```
$image  = $row['file_data'];
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$image['file_data'].'" alt="photo"><br>';
```

...or...

```
$im = imageCreateFromString($image);
```

I just wind up with a bunch of hexadecimal garbage on screen.

I intitially stored the Images using:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($resizedImage, null, 100);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$sql = sprintf(
 "insert into images (filename, mime_type, file_size, file_data, event_id)
 values ('%s', '%s', %d, '%s',%d)",
 mysql_real_escape_string($fileName),
 mysql_real_escape_string($mimeType),
 $imageSize,
 mysql_real_escape_string($content),
 $eventID 
);
$result = $cn->query($sql);
```

Does anyone PLEASE have a working code snippet to successfully display the stored .jpg mid-file in the PHP output?

Comment: It can be done, but... you don't really want to do this, it's a really bad practice.

Comment: user1068351: Please go to your SO profile and choose a nickname. Those default user1234567 nicks are not very nice to read. @Fosco: Depends for what you use it. But I agree, for a "photo" it *is* bad.

Answer (score 6):

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image['file_data']).'" alt="photo"><br>';
```

However, remember that old IE versions do not support this kind of inline images! Besides that, the browser cannot cache such an image except together with its containing HTML page.

Answer (score 4):

You should create some sort of "image server". You're already close to that.
For example, create something like image.php that will get a image name and will generate it on the fly.
So, for example, say you want to get somePic.jpg image. You can get it through:

image.php?name=somePic.jpg

```
<?php
header('Content-type: ' . $image['mime_type']);
echo $image['file_data'];
?>
```

Your  tag:

```
<img src='image.php?name=somePic.jpg' />
```

Or more general:

```
echo "<img src='image.php?name={$image['filename']}' />"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call your test page `image.php`, then have it called from the browser on the rendered page:

```
<img src="image.php?imageid=123" alt="photo" />
```